# I am trying to get keystroke in C# wpf but it's not working. Is my code wrong?

Tags: c#, keypress

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace clipper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void HandleKeyDownEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("It came here");

            if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl && e.Key == Key.C)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have pressed control + c");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So this is my code. I've tried googling the solution for keyPress event and I implemented it here. But as I am new to C#, I am not sure what went wrong. Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to change `KeyPreview` to `true`
and can you try `e.Modifiers` `event`. It may helps..

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    KeyPreview = true;
}

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Modifiers == (Keys.Shift | Keys.Control))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(".");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not using Form .. i am using wpf, and Maybe because of that i am getting an error for KeyPreview = ture;

Comment: Not only this, you forgot to attach the event: `this.KeyPreview = true;
            this.KeyPress +=
                new KeyPressEventHandler(HandleKeyDownEvent);`

Answer (score 1):

You should use Key_Up with the following code

```
private void textBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Key == Key.C) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have pressed control + c");
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not working. Its still not calling the Method. Do i have to have any object in UI to trigger this event ?

Comment: yes you need to have    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="206,128,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" KeyUp="textBox_KeyUp"/>

Comment: owh.. can i use something else than a TexBox ? like Button or something ? and change textBox_KeyUp to button_KeyUp ?

Comment: @laslavinco yes you can replace with button

Comment: <Button x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="206,128,0,0"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" KeyUp="textBox_KeyUp"/>

Comment: cool. And one last thing .. is it possible to get a capture a KeyStoke like a shortcut works in windows ? Like imagine i am on my desktop and i press Ctrl+C on a file so whatever i have copied in my clipboard like link of it should get pasted in my UI automatically ?

Comment: probably you can track the keys and add it to a element you want, mark as answer if it has helped